# Request: New tag: `capacitive-touch`

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have begun to ask questions about design of `capacitive-touch` interfaces, whether as touchscreens or buttons/sliders/wheels.

I did not find an associated tag.

The closest I could find were the `switches` and `capacitor`/`capacitance` tags. I feel that these are too broad. Additionally, I found the `touchscreen` tag, which can make use of capacitive touch, but that is not always the use (and in the case of my questions will not be the use).

Answer (score 4):

It's true that capacitive touch sensor applications are different from capacitive touchscreen applications.

I have some experience with capacitive touch sensor ICs for automotive OEMs, so I would probably watch this tag if it existed. But I haven't noticed any questions on this topic here thus far. Are there some existing [capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capacitor) / [capacitance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capacitance) questions that would benefit from being tagged capacitive-touch?

Also, when creating a new tag, it's best to have some clear definition in mind. When a contributor asks a question and has to choose some tags, the text that pops up comes from the Tag Info. See https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tags/info  Having a few clearly written sentences here helps the contributors and editors keep things organized.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/664268/capacitive-touch-board-penetrations

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/664267/capacitive-touch-multi-touch-simultaneous-read-self-capacitance-buttons

Comment: Do the above fit the bill? I started focusing on lithium ion cell power supply and LED driving, but I'll be back to the (cap touch) interfacing in the future : j

Comment: I already know I'll be asking about cap touch devoted interface ICs vs programming the microcontroller already needed in the system (like through TI's CapTIvate). There's also trying to use a grid touch IC's offering for numerous buttons on a not grid (where the nodes are instead clustered in different areas to form 'buttons' rather than a screen)